# Cardinality of $\left(\bigcup_{1}^{n} O_{i} \right) \cap K$, where $O_{i}, k$ are subgroups of odd order, is odd.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, finite-groups

I'm struggling to find some proof to the following statement:

> Let $G$ be a group and $O_{i},K$ be odd subgroups of $G$. Show that
>
> 1. $\left|\left(\bigcup_{1}^{n} O_{i} \right) \cap K\right|$ is odd;
> 2. $\left|\left(\bigcup_{1}^{n} O_{i} \right)\right|$ is odd.

As we don't have the amount of $O_{i}$, I can't proceed. Any help will be very appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried induction on $n$?

Comment: Actually, no. I'll give a try! Thanks @MatthewPilling

Comment: @MatthewPilling I could not continue, since I don't know who is $U_{n} \cap K$.

Comment: I would show $(2)$ first. $(1)$ directly follows from $(2)$ by observing $$\Bigg(\bigcup_{i=1}^n O_i\Bigg)\cap K = \bigcup_{i=1}^n Q_i$$ where $Q_i=O_i\cap K\leq G$.

Comment: @MatthewPilling Nice! But, why is $Q_{i}$ odd?

Comment: $Q_i$ is a subgroup of $K$ which has odd cardinality. Since $|Q_i|$ divides $|K|$ by Lagrange's theorem, we know $|Q_i|$ has to be odd.

Comment: @MatthewPilling I'll try to be direct: Lets suppose that $|\bigcup_{i=1}^{m} O_{i}|$ is odd (induction). Now $\bigcup_{i=1}^{m} O_{i} \cup O_{m+1}$ may have a odd number of elements more? How can I prove that the amount of "new" elements is even? This is where I'm having some problems. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your induction hypothesis is that $\bigcup_{i=1}^n O_i$ is odd for *any* collection of $n-$ odd subgroups $O_1,...,O_n$ of $G$. Now suppose $A_1,...,A_{n+1}$ is a collection of ${n+1}$ odd subgroups of $G$. Can you use the fact that $$|X\cup Y|=|X|+|Y|-|X\cap Y|$$ to justify the induction step?

Comment: @MatthewPilling So we need first to prove $(1)$, since we need to use that $|X \cap Y|$ is odd. Thinking now, maybe using the inclusion-exclusion on $(1)$ may help. I'll give a try.

Comment: You don't need to prove $(1)$ first. Just take $$X=\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i, Y=A_{n+1}$$ and write $X\cap Y$ as $\bigcup_{i=1}^n Q_i$ where $Q_i=A_i\cap A_{n+1}$. Note $Q_1,...,Q_n$ is a collection of $n-$ odd subgroups of $G$